# Connectors for Sharepoint Federated Search

Tags: sharepoint, search-server, search

we're setting up Federated Search on our intranet, and this blog:
http://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/blogs/adawson/archive/2008/08/01/sharepoint-federated-search.aspx

indicates that there is an on-line gallery for searching other external sources, eg Yahoo

The link for the gallery is: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=95798, which initally led to:
http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-connectors.aspx

but which now gets redirected to:
http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/Pages/Editions-Comparison.aspx?Capability=Search

which isn't what I was looking for at all ...

Does anybody know what's happened here/let us have a nice Yahoo connector?

thanks

Toby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is kind of silly, but if you add `#none` to the end of the URL, it will go to the old page.

http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-connectors.aspx#none

You might report this to Microsoft's web people using the "Contact Us" button at the bottom of the page - it seems like a bug due to them rearranging their SharePoint sites after the 2010 launch.

Comment: that does seem a little silly, but it works! thanks!